# How to push working copy to remote server using git

Tags: git, push

I pulled the project from remote server and i have done some changes to local workig copy, now I need an advice on how to push my working copy of project to local git server.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [add a new remote](http://progit.org/book/ch2-5.html) to your working repository that points to the "*local git server*". For example you might add a remote called `local`:

```
git remote add local git://myserver/myproject.git
```

Then you can simply *push* your commits to the `local` repository:

```
git commit -m "I've changed this and that"
git push local
```

Comment: thanks, but the files from remote repository have been pushed to local   server repository, even if i do :                                       `$  git add .` before `$ git push local`

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you. Correct me if I'm wrong:

1) You *pulled* a project from a **remote repository** with `git pull git://remoteserver/project.git`
2) You *commited* some changes to your **working copy** with `git add .` followed by `git commit -m "My changes"`
3) You want to *push* the changes from your **working copy** to **another repository** that you call *local*.

Is this correct?

Comment: I forgot to `git commit -m` . Enrico Thanks!